# login code not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, html

i've used a login for my application..firstly i used admin login only and it was working perfectly, but now when i added teacher and student logins as well, but i cudnt find a problem, its not logging me inn.,, but just redirecting to unauthorized access pleas help

login.php

```php
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admdin Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="login-action.php">
    <label>User Name:</label> <input type="text" name="un" />
    <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="pd" />  <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<a href="forgot-password.php">Forgot Password?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

this is     login-action.php

```php
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php

$uid=$_POST["un"];
$pwd=$_POST["pd"];
$encpwd=md5($pwd);
$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (email='".$uid."' AND   password='".$encpwd."')");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows > 0) {

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
   $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
   $_SESSION['type'] = $row['type'];
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

   $_SESSION["loggedin"]=true;
}
}
else {
 $_SESSION["loggedin"]=false;
}

mysql_close($con);

if ($_SESSION["loggedin"])
{
if ($_SESSION["type"]=="A")
    {
        $_SESSION["isadmin"]=true;
    }

if ($_SESSION["type"]=="T")
    {
        $_SESSION["isteacher"]=true;
    }
if ($_SESSION["type"]=="S")
     {
         $_SESSION["isstudent"]=true;
     }

 }
if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
{
header("Location: $fullpath"."admin/000.php");
}

if ($_SESSION["isteacher"])
{
header("Location:$fullpath"."teacher/");
}

if ($_SESSION["isstudent"])
{
header("Location:$fullpath"."student/");
}

else {
   header("Location: $fullpath"."login/unauthorized.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your query works, and is getting the correct information in `$result`?

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: Don't mean to be obvious but did you double-check the capitalization? The case sensitive nature of usernames/passwords has tripped me up many times before.

Comment: Perhaps your session type is the wrong case: `a, t, s` instead of `A, T, S`

Comment: You should not be storing raw passwords in your database; you should encrypt them.  See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt

Comment: thanks for giving so much useful information :) i'll check that but i really dont know about sql injection and dont knw how to avoid them... :(
yup i double checked everything, i dont know where is the problem..
yup i used md5 for encryption, im not ustoring passwords as it is,... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
    {
        header("Location: $fullpath"."admin/000.php");
    }

    elseif ($_SESSION["isteacher"])
    {
        header("Location:$fullpath"."teacher/");
    }

    elseif ($_SESSION["isstudent"])
    {
        header("Location:$fullpath"."student/");
    }

    else {
        header("Location: $fullpath"."login/unauthorized.php");
    }
```

Comment: Mike i alter the code as u said but its still not working... isnt there any problem in the    $_SESSION["loggedin"]  and the code in it???

Comment: I would stick an echo "No User Found!"; just before or after $_SESSION["loggedin"]=false; to see if its even setting those values